# Движок браузера на .net

Tags: .net, webbrowser

Есть ли движок браузера, который написан полностью на .net, без использования нативного кода вообще? Видел вебкит и т.д., но они вроде как не полностью на дотнет, а используют какие-то нативные библиотеки.

Comment: Webkit на .next? Вы, пардон, что курите?

Comment: WebKit на С++ написан. Скорее всего вы видлели .NET обертку к нему.

Comment: Движок браузера на .net... Это было бы забавно. Тормозило бы, наверное, неслабо...

Comment: >Тормозило бы, наверное, неслабо...

Какие доказательства?

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/Vpo3kPF.jpg

Comment: Ну что такое .NET? Это виртуальная машина, это стандартные контейнеры, это garbage collector, который за программиста делает грязную работу, это интерфейсы повсюду... Это всё ускоряет разработку, но бесплатным быть не может. Это тратит процессор, память и уменьшает контроль программиста над происходящим

Comment: Спасибо, кэп. Речь не об этом, а о том, что ваше утверждение несколько безосновательно и подкреплено не фактами реальных замеров производительности, а оценочными суждениями. Я думаю, ни для кого не секрет, что производительность С++ выше, чем C#/Java/etc. Однако "медленнее, чем на C++" еще не означает, что "тормозило бы, наверное, неслабо", я обращал внимание именно на это. Возможно, тормозило бы, и возможно, что не слабо, но все же далеко не факт

Comment: Ну, исходный вопрос не в том, на сколько % будет медленнее. Просто моё мнение, обоснование - выше, подробно обсуждать не готов. Разве что добавить, что, по ощущениям - минимум в 2-3 раза. Учитывая, что и нативные браузеры не очень чтобы летают...

Comment: просто я помню, видел какие-то тесты, в которых показывалось, что C++ значительно эффективнее C# только в случае довольно агрессивной оптимизации под конкретную платформу, тогда как в остальных ситуациях он выигрывает далеко не в разы, а максимум на несколько десятков процентов. 

Но вообще, если по сабжу, то помимо скорости немаловажным  является и тот факт, что .net не кроссплатформенная технология. Если же брать такую реализацию, как Mono, то вот она как раз в производительности существенно проигрывает даже реализации от MS

Comment: что это за школьное творчество, стесняюсь спросить? И где тут движок на .NET?

Comment: Конечно же я оговорился про вебкит, это же очевидно, т.к. я же и писал в своем посте "а используют какие-то нативные библиотеки". Не нужно умничать, тем более рассказывать что такое .net и как все будет тормозить. Движок ie тоже мне не нужен, спасибо. Если нет ответа, можно же мимо пройти.

Comment: Раз в гугле не нашли, значит нет.

Comment: И опять "на Java/C#/etc. будет медленнее"... JIT. Vs. standart compilation. Так вот, на мелких проектах интерпретируемые будут тормозить, но на крупных... Если выделить отдельные часто работающие методы, то они постепенно сильно ускорятся.(скомпилируятся, "когда будет время") Потому что метод, скомпилированный под конкретную машину (причём под конкретное раб. состояние - вдруг комп вырубят, поменяют кол-во оперативы и врубят. Тогда придётся перекомпилировать) будет работать быстрее, чем метод, скомпилированный пусть даже под конкретную ос. Уж это инфа 100%)

Comment: Ну да, в этом же вся фишка и была, если верить Рихтеру. Что JIT'ter учитывает информацию о системе, доступную в риал-тайме, а-ля тип процессора, разрядность АЛУ, систему команд и дополнительные архитектурные расширения а-ля наличие наборов инструкций MMX\XMM и на основе этого уже генерить самый эффективный код. А сгенеренный код уже помещается в кэш откомпилированных методов, и их не нужно потом заново компилить.