# Примеры выигрыша по скорости за счёт JIT-компиляции

Tags: производительность, компиляция

[Как-то](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/253230/webbrowser-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-net) здесь чуть не разгорелась дискуссия на счёт того, какие языки быстрее, компилируемые в исполняемый файл или компилируемые "на лету" (а изначально - интерпретируемые или компилируемые на виртуальную машины). В связи с чем было бы здорово увидеть примеры, когда JIT-код выигрывал за счёт более точной подстройки под текущую машину.

Лично я скептически отношусь к этому. Я не думаю, что количество памяти или размер кэша процессора может быть с существенной пользой использовано компилятором. И не думаю, что можно получить эффект от учёта имеющихся расширений системы команд процессора (MMX, SSE, ...). Т.к., во-первых, автоматическое распознавание блоков программы, которые могут быть распараллелены, достаточно сложно, а во-вторых, при обычной компиляции может быть сгенерировано несколько вариантов машинного кода - для разных наборов команд.

Comment: Максимум, о чем можно спорить, это о том, что компилируемые на лету языки не сильно медленнее, чем компилируемые в исполняемый код (конечно мы говорим о развитых языках с развитыми компиляторами, например C++ vs Java). 

Кроме того, любой пример всегда будет привязан к конкретным компиляторам и виртуальным машинам (вплоть до номера билда в версии), к конкрентым процам и т.п.

В теории искомые вами примеры возможны. Возможно, что они даже встречались на практике. Но все это так мимолетно.

Answer (score 1):

Вспомнил [51 выпуск](http://taop.rpod.ru/167365.html) подкаста The Art Of Programming, там с 9:30 (лучше конечно с начала послушать) человек из Sun Microsystems на примере Java объясняет плюсы JIT-компиляции.